# Javascript url-redirection with pound-bang char in path

Tags: javascript

How can I redirect my url from the form :

```
 http://example.com/#!foo
```

to the form :

```
http://example.com/folder/#!foo
```

using javascript?

I know that url redirection with hashbang is imposible on server side because # is never sent to the server.

I have tried the following code but redirection is not happening.

```
<script>
 window.open("http://example.com/folder/window.location.pathname);

</script>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
window.location.assign(<the path you want>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
window.open('http://example.com/folder/'+window.location.hash);
```

As you said, the hash tag will not pass to server anyway.