# url redirection with hash-bang char is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect my incoming urls from the from :

```
 http://example.com/#!foo
```

to the form :

```
 http://example.com/folder/#!foo
```

How can I do it using javascript?

I tried

```
 window.open('http://example.com/'+window.location.hash);
```

But the page is not redirecting.

Any idea?

Comment: any reason you asked this question [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984544/javascript-url-redirection-with-pound-bang-char-in-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why my previous attempts to redirect the hash-bang urls failed, but after a few modifications my code worked fine. I changed **window.open()** to **window.location.assign()** .

```
 window.location.assign("http://www.example.com/folder/"+window.location.hash)
```